# Django - Where IN with multiple columns/fields

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I have a query that needs to fetch from a table that meets two columns requirements exactly. So if I have `users` table with columns, `age` and `score`.

```
SELECT * FROM users where (age, score) IN ((5,6), (9,12), (22,44)..);
```

In my web app, I am getting these pairs from an ajax request, and the number could be quite big. How do I construct a query for this in Django?

I am working on `Postgres` database

Comment: Same problem here. @Giorgi solution will work, but I doubt it efficency. Althoigh if you have short IN list, like 2-4 records it will fine I think.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I come up with, would be to use [`django.db.models.Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object and construct exactly same query as you've written:

```
ques = Q(age=5) & Q(score=6) | Q(age=9) & Q(score=12) ...
User.objects.filter(ques)
```

This would return the desired queryset, but, I'd be concerned about the size of the iteration performance of the received values (using ajax).

On the other hand, I don't recall better solution for now. If something comes up, would update the answer. Hope, this helps.

Comment: It will generate query, that will do exactly same thing. But I doubt it efficency. For example IN will use index. This solution - I'm not sure.

Comment: Right, I absolutely agree, if set is too large, the performance would be an issue. But I don't see better way from the context of the question, do you?

Comment: I checked the query generated by this answer using print(queryset.query). Executed it using explain (eg. explain select * from something). The explanation generated is the same for both the queries. So, I'm assuming this answer doesn't have any perforamnce issues.